# How to delete a Record from database with ID that exists using java

Tags: java, jdbc

so I want to Delete a record using ID but my code does not check if the ID Exists or not and I tried several method I just do not know what is the problem.

That is my code

```
 int ID;

 String DatabaseName = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/JobPortalDB";

 String username = "DB";

 String password = "1234";

 String sql = " DELETE FROM Job WHERE JobID=?";


 try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseName, username, password); PreparedStatement prepstatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

     ID = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());


     int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to delete This permenantly? ", "Delete Job", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

     if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
         prepstatement.setInt(1, ID);


         prepstatement.executeUpdate();

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.jTextField1, "your Operation was successfuly Done", "info", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

     }
     if (option == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

         return;
     }

 } catch (SQLException ex) {


     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
         ex.getMessage(), "Database error",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
 }
```

Comment: We also do not know what the problem is based on your description. Please describe your problem. Do you get an error, or does something unexpected happen? If so, what? If you get an exception, then please post the exception stacktrace. Also, why did you feel it was relevant to include _"but my code does not check if the ID Exists or not"_, do you want to check for existence first (which is a bit of an anti-pattern), or do you just want to know if something actually was deleted, or was there another reason you mentioned this?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the existence of the ID before deleting by using the select statement and count the result.

```
String sql = "select * from job where job = "+JobId ;
try{
    PreparedStatement ps =cnn.prepareStatement(sql) ; 
  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);
  int c=0 ; 
  while(rs.next()){
      c++ ; 
  } 
if(c>0){
  //delete
 }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.jTextField1,"user does not exist","info",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }
```

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting; I have edited it out. Checking for existence before deleting is an anti-pattern, and if you do, then using `select count(*)` is preferable over `select *` and 'manually' counting (or `select 1 from ... fetch first row only` and using `if (rs.next())` to confirm if there is at least one row)